# How can i populate other fields and dropdowns in my HTML based on the selection of one particular Json object from the first dropdown in angularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, select, dropdown

Below is the `JSON` object and code I have. I need to populate the Account type of a particular account selected in the first dropdown.
Currently the second `dropdown(Type)` is populated from the second array as below. But i want it to be auto populated based on the selection of the account number

from first one.

```
var arrIMAcctNbrs = [{ID:"124568",type:"Loan"}, {ID:"874559",type:"Loan"},    {ID:"785452",type:"Saving"},{ID:"1256422",type:"Deposit"}];

var arrAcctTypes= ["Deposit","Saving","Loan"];

    <div>
    <label class="label">Account Number</label>
    <select name="cboAcctNbr" id="cboAcctNbr" ng-model="acctNbr" >
     <option ng-repeat="valAcct in arrIMAcctNbr"  value="{{valAcct}}" >{{valAcct.ID}}</option>
    </select><br><br>
</div>
<div>
<label class="label">Account Type</label>   
    <select name="cboAcctTyp" id="cboAcctTyp"  ng-model="acctTyp">
      <option ng-repeat="valAcctTyp in arrAcctTypes" value="valAcctTyp">{{valAcctTyp}}</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Angularjs documentation it is better to use [**ng-options**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)
because it provides some benefits:-

- More flexibility in how the 's model is assigned via the
  select as part of the comprehension expression
- Reduced memory consumption by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance
- Increased render speed by creating the options in a documentFragment instead of individually

Anyway the following answer is based on your question that meas using ng-repat directive.

Following are the changes made from your code.

1. The value in ng-options of cboAcctTyp is remove
2. Added an ng-change directive to  cboAcctNbr

Here is a working demo with the changes made.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.arrIMAcctNbr = [{
    ID: "124568",
    type: "Loan"
  }, {
    ID: "874559",
    type: "Loan"
  }, {
    ID: "785452",
    type: "Saving"
  }, {
    ID: "1256422",
    type: "Deposit"
  }];

  $scope.arrAcctTypes = ["Deposit", "Saving", "Loan"];
  $scope.changeAccountType = function(acctNbr) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(acctNbr).type)
    $scope.acctTyp = JSON.parse(acctNbr).type
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>

<body ng-controller="controller">

  <div>
    <label class="label">Account Number</label>
    <select name="cboAcctNbr" id="cboAcctNbr" ng-model="acctNbr" ng-change="changeAccountType(acctNbr)">
         <option ng-repeat="valAcct in arrIMAcctNbr"  value="{{valAcct}}"  >{{valAcct.ID}}</option>
        </select><br><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="label">Account Type</label>{{acctTyp}}
    <select name="cboAcctTyp" id="cboAcctTyp" ng-model="acctTyp">
          <option ng-repeat="valAcctTyp in arrAcctTypes track by $index" >{{valAcctTyp}}</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ng-model="acctNbr". acctNbr is the valAcct.ID hence the ng-change="changeAccountType(acctNbr) doesnot work. is there any way i can store the valAcct  and pass in ng-change?

Comment: you can add a function that converts  valAcct.ID to acctNbr object

Answer (score 0):

Use [**ng-change**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to set default value for second dropdown on first dropdown change.

```
<div>
        <label class="label">Account Number</label>
        <select id="cboAcctNbr" ng-model="acctNbr" ng-options="valAcct.ID for valAcct in arrIMAcctNbrs" ng-change="acctTyp=acctNbr.type">
            </select><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="label">Account Type</label>
        <select id="cboAcctTyp" ng-model="acctTyp" ng-options="valAcctTyp for valAcctTyp in arrAcctTypes">
            </select>
      </div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.arrIMAcctNbrs = [{
    ID: "124568",
    type: "Loan"
  }, {
    ID: "874559",
    type: "Loan"
  }, {
    ID: "785452",
    type: "Saving"
  }, {
    ID: "1256422",
    type: "Deposit"
  }];

  $scope.arrAcctTypes = ["Deposit", "Saving", "Loan"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    <label class="label">Account Number</label>
    <select id="cboAcctNbr" ng-model="acctNbr" ng-options="valAcct.ID for valAcct in arrIMAcctNbrs" ng-change="acctTyp=acctNbr.type">
        </select><br><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="label">Account Type</label>
    <select id="cboAcctTyp" ng-model="acctTyp" ng-options="valAcctTyp for valAcctTyp in arrAcctTypes">
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-model="acctNbr" in the first dropdown has the value of account number. Hence ng-change="acctTyp=acctNbr.type" doesnot work.

Comment: "acctNbr" is having both accountNumber and type. See the above working example